# Daily html email report, problem with tsql

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2014

We have a daily report generated and getting info from a table but the email that's sent doesn't show the "Results2" but if I only ask the Select query it works fine.
Here's the script:

```
DECLARE @tableHTML  NVARCHAR(MAX) ;
DECLARE @tableHTML1  NVARCHAR(MAX) ;



SET @tableHTML1 =
    N'<H2>DailyCheck</H2>' +
    N'<table border="1">' +
    N'<tr><th>Results1</th><th>Results2</th></tr>' +
                           ISNULL(CAST ( (                          
           SELECT  *    
FROM        
(        
   SELECT    
       a.ToDevice, count(distinct p.Email) as 'result'
   FROM    
       Database..AccountTransfer a (nolock)
       join Database..Person p (nolock) on p.VTKId = a.VTkId
   GROUP BY    
       a.ToDevice
) as innerTable    
WHERE        
   result >= 4    
ORDER BY        
   result desc
     FOR XML PATH('tr'), TYPE 
    ) AS NVARCHAR(MAX)), 'No result found') +
    N'</table>' ;


    SET @tableHTML = N'<H1>Daily Check ' + CONVERT(VARCHAR(20), GETDATE() ,120)  + '</h1>' + @tableHTML1 + '</br>'

EXEC msdb.dbo.sp_send_dbmail
@profile_name = 'Email',
@recipients = 'reciever@email.net',
@subject = 'Daily check query',
@body = @tableHTML,
@body_format = 'HTML'
```

This is the result we get in the email that is sent: (results2 doesn't show anything)

```
        DailyCheck
    Results1    Results2
    DFFBB78B-811C-481E-BA33-85B7512960E1114 
    F6ACB39D-7D91-48EE-B2A0-324B48DB26E847
```

And if we only run

```
SELECT  * FROM        
    (        
       SELECT    
           a.ToDevice, count(distinct p.Email) as 'result'
       FROM    
           Database..AccountTransfer a (nolock)
           join Database..Person p (nolock) on p.VTKId = a.VTkId
       GROUP BY    
           a.ToDevice
    ) as innerTable    
    WHERE        
       result >= 4    
    ORDER BY        
       result desc
```

Then we get this result: (results2 are showing results)

```
    Results1    Results2
DFFBB78B-811C-481E-BA33-85B7512960E1    114
F6ACB39D-7D91-48EE-B2A0-324B48DB26E8    47
```

Anyone have any thoughts to what could be wrong? Something with the code?

Here's only the HTML code:

```
DECLARE @tableHTML  NVARCHAR(MAX) ;
DECLARE @tableHTML1  NVARCHAR(MAX) ;



SET @tableHTML1 =
    N'<H2>DailyCheck</H2>' +
    N'<table border="1">' +
    N'<tr><th>Results1</th><th>Results2</th></tr>' +

     FOR XML PATH('tr'), TYPE 
    ) AS NVARCHAR(MAX)), 'No result found') +
    N'</table>' ;


    SET @tableHTML = N'<H1>Daily Check ' + CONVERT(VARCHAR(20), GETDATE() ,120)  + '</h1>' + @tableHTML1 + '</br>'

EXEC msdb.dbo.sp_send_dbmail
@profile_name = 'Email',
@recipients = 'reciever@email.net',
@subject = 'Daily check query',
@body = @tableHTML,
@body_format = 'HTML'
```

Comment: And what is exactly the problem? Both show same result.

Comment: The "Results" isn't showing any results at all in the email that is sent. When running the Select query only you see the results "114, 47" but in the email result it doesn't show.

Comment: Can you post @tableHTML value?. IMHO this has nothing to do with database, it is more about HTML code.

Comment: The first script is the full script that send the daily email report, there's nothing else that I've left out. I know that it doesn't have anything to do with the database, the question is if there's something wrong with the HTML code och the Select query that gives a different results when running only the Select query and when running it with HTML code.

Comment: Well, post the resultat HTML code just we can analyze it.  Should `FOR XML PATH('tr')` be `FOR XML PATH('<tr>')`?

Comment: I've posted only the HTML code below. Also tried changing ('tr') to ('<tr>') but still the same results.

Comment: Sorry maybe I've not explained it in the correct way, instead of `exec msdb.dbo.sp_send_dbmail` add a `select @tableHTML` at end of your code and post the html text. And please don't add an answer, you can edit your original question.

Comment: HTML tables are `<tr>` and `<td>`. Based on the fact you only have `<tr>`, this is completely not a SQL question.

Comment: I believe when @McNets was asking you to post the HTML code, he meant the generated HTML, not the pieces of the SQL code that have to do with HTML. (He said "code" probably because HTML is a markup language, thus the tags comprising an HTML page could be considered, in a broader sense, "code".)

Comment: This is the results if I do a Select @TableHTML `<H1>Daily Check 2018-03-14 09:00:54</h1><H2>Results1</H2><table border="1"><tr><th>Results1</th><th>Results2</th></tr><tr><ToDevice>DFFBB78B-811C-481E-BA33-85B7512960E1</ToDevice><result>114</result></tr><tr><ToDevice>F6ACB39D-7D91-48EE-B2A0-324B48DB26E8</ToDevice><result>48</result></tr><tr><ToDevice>1F73C686-243E-41F4-B3D6-963A50195E5F</ToDevice><result>45</result></tr><tr>`

Comment: @MarkSinkinson I see what you mean and I get the issue now, the Results2 are shown at the end of Results1 in the email. But how can I rewrite the Select query to have the `<td` in it?

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to the help I was able to understand how it worked a little better. What I did was to edit this part:

```
   SELECT    
       a.ToDevice AS TD, count(distinct p.Email) as 'result'
   FROM
```

This solved it for me, thanks everyone who helped!